# Partial derivative being $0$ implies non-dependence on that coordinate for $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $U \in \mathbb{R}^n$ open and convex

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and convex and $f : U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ differentiable such that $\partial_1f(x)=0$ for all $x \in U.$
Show that the value of $f(x)$ for $x = (x_1,...,x_n) \in U$ does not depend
on $x_1.$

$\text{Proof:}$

Suppose for a contradiction that $f$ depends on the first coordinate. Let $x,y \in U$ be such that $x_i=y_i$ except for $i=1.$ Since $U$ is open and convex we can use the Mean Value Theorem. Hence there is $c= t_0x+(1-t_0)y,$ for some $t_0 \in [0,1]$ such that
\begin{align*}
f(x)-f(y)
&=\nabla f(c)\cdot\langle x-y \rangle\\
&=\langle 0,\partial_2f(c),...,\partial_nf(c) \rangle \cdot \langle x_1-y_1,0,...,0 \rangle \\
&=0.
\end{align*}

Therefore, we have that $f(x)=f(y),$ which is a contraction, since $f$ is not constant. Thus, $f$ does not depend on the first coordinate.

Is this the correct approach to this problem? Any feedback is much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, this looks good. You can drop the "If $f$ is constant..." sentence, by the way.

Comment: @LukasGeyer Thank you for the feedback. I edited the proof as suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is fine, but it is needless to phrase it as a proof by contradiction. The same computation that you did shows that $g(t) = f(t,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ is a constant function, which is all you want. As a matter of style, direct proofs are preferred to proofs by contradiction.